# Convert WebRequest into httpclient in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpwebrequest

Got this code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.Timeout = 3000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

how to convert this code into httpclient since WebRequest.Create(host) is obsolete, this code is called on the first time app open, located in formload to check internet connection active and host/domain I check is up

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it this way, just notice it's async.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, host));
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Mind that you shouldn't be using `HttpClient` in a `using`, _usually_. Since this is a one-shot request here, it should be fine in this case.

Comment: @Fildor so what is a disadvantage of `using` in this case?

Comment: I said _in this case_ it is fine.

Comment: @Fildor its fine, but when we should not use it? Can you please give example? I want to learn

Comment: Sure. You can directly refer to its docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#instancing